# Need Help on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 Static Routing

Tags: networking, server, netplan, routing

I am currently having a difficult time configuring a Static Route. I have an Asterisk Server Hosted on my Ubuntu Server Machine, It has 2 NICs

```
eth0;
IP Address: 172.16.1.99
GW: 172.16.1.1

eth1
IP Address: 10.20.0.3
GW: 10.20.0.1
```

I have a SIP Trunk (LAN: 172.16.1.98) with an External IP of 20.211.3.12 which responds only to packets coming from eth0 (172.16.1.99). When I try to do a trace route on the External IP I can see that it is exiting eth1 (10.20.0.3) hence, no ping reply is being received. Basically, What I need to is route all traffic intended for 20.211.3.12 and 172.16.1.98 to use eth0.

I've done this on my netplan but doesn't seem to work, any advice?

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses: [172.16.1.99/23]
            gateway4: 172.16.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [172.16.1.1,8.8.8.8]
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
              - to: 10.211.3.0/24
                via: 172.16.1.1
        eth1:
            addresses: [10.20.0.3/24]
            gateway4: 10.20.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [10.20.0.1,8.8.4.4]
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
              - to: 172.16.1.0/23
                via: 10.20.0.1
              - to: 10.211.3.0/24
                via: 172.16.1.1
              - to: 10.211.3.12/32
                via: 172.16.1.99
    version: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be declaring a route

```
- to: 10.211.3.12/32
  via: 172.16.1.98
```

attached to your eth0 interface.

Comment: That worked great!! Thanks